# HTTPS_CATALOG for retrieving images?

Tags: php, html, opencart

I'm in the middle of retrieving product's image into my order detail page. I'm working on a webpage using Opencart. In the admin page file (admin\view\template\sale\order_info.tpl) , the code below is what I've found to retrieve image and it succeed

```
<img src="<?php echo HTTPS_CATALOG."image/".$productinfo->row['image']; ?>" width="90" height="90" />
```

but when i put the same code to my template\account\order_info.tpl which will take effect on the user / customer interface, this code doesn't work. The product's image didn't show up.

is HTTPS_CATALOG code missing something ? 
since I'm a beginner in PHP i don't really know much about this..
Please tell me if my description wasn't clear enough and Thank You very much beforehand.

Comment: Where exactly did you get $productinfo->row from??? That's not standard OC as far as I know

Comment: @JayGilford That's because nowadays nobody is following the standards (I mean the OC standards) but I can see in every question here and there users using their *beautiful* style copied from *genius* PHP books and some dubious PHP *how-to-dos*... Even few answers are breaking MVC in OC and suggests using SQL queries directly in templates... Sometimes I want to puke reading code in questions here...

Comment: @shadyyx - I feel the same way every time I see a custom themeforest template for OC - look great, but coded way off standard

Answer (score 0):

In catalog side (the `account\order_info.tpl` belongs to catalog side) `HTTPS_SERVER` is equivalent of `HTTPS_CATALOG`.

See `config.php` and `admin/config.php` for all defined contants. Catalog side uses former and admin side uses latter.

Also as jay said in comment `$productinfo->row` is not in the default code of opencart, so make sure you are doing everthing right and not just blindly copy pasting.